# How to create function that takes in strings and converts to int if string equals 'one'

Tags: python

I have a function that looks like this:

```
def test(in1):

  if in2 = 151:
    print('error')


  if in2 == 1:
    in1 = 14
    print(in1)
```

The function currently takes in a string value,

I was thinking:

```
if in2 == 'one':
   in2 = 14
```

But that doesn't work for some reason

Thanks

Comment: But you aren’t testing to see if the value of the string is `'one'`? Also to test if `int` use `isinstance(in2, int)`

Comment: see reply below...you don't need to convert 'one' to 1, you can just directly assign the value 1 to your variable..

Comment: @jackiegirl89 you'll have to write a dict to do that. I can't think of any other way than have a dict with key being the string and value being the int. Assuming what you want is to be able to convert written numbers to integers.

Comment: @SuperShoot: Thanks for finding this.  The only duplicates I recalled were in Java and C++; I couldn't find this one.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want the following?

```
if in2 == 'one':
    in2 = 1
```

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question at hand.

Comment: it's an attempt to reply and help to a not well stated question, your comment isn't helping anyone at all though

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to convert `'one'` to an integer which won't work because python doesn't know that the word one refers to the integer 1. What you need to do is put `in2 = 1` in the body of your if-statement.

```
if in2 == 'one':
       in2 = 1
```

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question at hand.

Comment: I disagree. I addressed why their current code isn't working and how they could achieve what they specifically asked in the post.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because the `int` conversion works only on the string image of an integer *numeral*.  `int("1")` would work.

Python does not have a built-in function to convert text strings to numbers.  You will need to provide that with some sort of conversion function of your own.  In the restricted example you gave, it's simply a matter of

```
if in2 = "one":
    in2 = 1
```

However, you seem to want a more general solution.  There are programs you can look up for converting number phrases to integers in general.  For now, you may want simply a look-up table; a `dict` works well for this.

```
str_to_int = {
      "one": 1, "two": 2, "three":3,      # Continue as far as you need
    }
```

Now, you can do something such as

```
if in2 in str_to_int:
    in2 = str_to_int[in2]
```

This is still awkward programming, as it does very little for error cases, and you've used one variable for two distinct purposes -- neither of which is apparent from its name.  However, fixing all of those problems would involve an overhaul, better done on your own time.

Answer (score -1):

```
num_str = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
num_int = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
if(in2 in num_str):
    foo = num_str.index(in2)
    output = num_int[foo]
    return output
```

This should work because you have a pre-defined list of numbers but spelled out. If your function parameter is equal to a string in this list, it will get the according integer from the list of numbers in integer form and return it.